# Single query in which multiplication in query and get sum of that multiplication

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I Have a table which shown below
[image: My Table Image]

This is fixed table no value will be added.now i wants multiplication of first 5 id with 5, next 3 id with 4 and next 2 id with 5.

And Get Sum Of Totals which i received as upon.

In This Example I Need Output 25+12+10 = **47**

Comment: Not with you, Should 5*5 not be (5*1) + (5*2) + (5*3) + (5*4) + (5*5) = 75?

Comment: No
Total Count(id) * 5

Comment: So where does the table come into it and why the chunks 5,3,2? Or are you saying each name can have up to 10 id's where the first 5 ids for the name should acquire 25 but if name has only 2 ids then should acquire 10 (for example)?

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be 2*5=10? which makes the total 25+12+10 = 47 ?

Comment: that is a Fixed Values. 
in this table first 5 id is multiplied by 5.
than other 3 id multiplied by 4.
and in last two id multiplied by 5.
And final i need sum of this multiplied value

Comment: Right @Krishnakumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand the reason behind your particular request. I'm not sure if you need a generic result as well.

Having said that, for the above example, the below query should give you the requested output:

```
select (select count(*) from table where id in (1,2,3,4,5))*5+(select  
count(*) from table where id in (6,7,8))*4+((select count(*) from table 
where id in (9,10))*5) as TOTAL;
```

Comment: It's working perfectly but what if i have table with 30 Data? Did i have to put all data in ( bracket ) ?

Comment: @Webster Yes, your solution below will work. As said in my answer, your expected output wasn't very clear - on why you need to do this. whether you needed a generic output or just for your example.

Comment: Thanks @Krishnakumar

Answer (score 0):

```
select ( 
        select count(*) from `prepare_test` where id <= 5 
    )*5 + 
    ( 
        select count(*) from prepare_test where id >= 6 and id <=8
    )*4 + 
    ( 
        (select count(*) from prepare_test where id >= 9 and id <=10)*5 
    ) as TOTAL
```

Its working smoothly.and also work with large amount of data in mysql table.